# C++ std::function causes segment faults

Tags: c++

Could anyone tell me why below code will lead to a segment fault? And it's weird that calling function `f3` is ok, but calling function `f4` will lead to a segment fault.

And if I use capture by reference in `ComposableFunction`, both `f3` and `f4` work fine...

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename R>
struct ComposableFunction {
    std::function<R(T)> func;

    template<typename O>
    ComposableFunction<T, O> then(std::function<O(R)> thenFunc) {
        return {[=](T t) -> O { return thenFunc(func(t)); }};
    }
};

int plus99(int i) {
    return i + 99;
}

int main() {
    ComposableFunction<int, int> f0 {&plus99};
    std::function<int(int)> f3 = f0.then<int>(&plus99).then<int>(&plus99).func;
    cout << f3(1999) << endl;  // this line is ok
    std::function<int(int)> f4 = f0.then<int>(&plus99).then<int>(&plus99).then<int>(&plus99).func;
    cout << f4(1999) << endl;  // this line will lead to a segment fault
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of temporary objects used in those expressions, temporary objects which will have been destructed once you call `f3` and `f4`.

Comment: If you want to compose functions, however, just write a composition function, so that `compose(f,g)` is the composition of `f` and `g`, whaterver those `f` and `g` are, without requiring them to be wrapped in a `ComposableFunction` object. Or just use [`boost::hana::compose`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga3b16146e53efcdf9ecbb9a7b21f8cd0b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice one. **Your code captures `*this` by reference**, and that reference quickly becomes dangling.

> if I use capture by reference in `ComposableFunction`, both `f3` and `f4` work fine

That causes even more references to dangle, so it's not a solution.

GCC warns about this with `-Wall -Wextra`, but doesn't explain it very well. Clang needs `-Wdeprecated`, but produces a nicer warning:

```
warning: implicit capture of 'this' with a capture default of '=' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-this-capture]
note: add an explicit capture of 'this' to capture '*this' by reference
```

It tells you that you're effectively capturing `this`, i.e. the current object by reference.

The fix is to explicitly capture `*this` instead, to make a copy. Note the `*`.

Also, I would explicitly move `thenFunc` into the lambda, by writing `thenFunc = std::move(thenFunc)` in the capture list. Because otherwise it's being copied.

Comment: moving is wrong without qualifying then member as an rvalue nethod.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks, I overlooked that. Edited.